# Localization of iOS Storyboard: UITextView texts are not localized?

Tags: ios, localization, uitextview, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard based application, which is localized from German to English.

Most strings in the UI are correctly pulled from the Main.strings files, with the exception of all text in UITextViews, although they do appear in Main.strings file:

```
/* Class = "IBUITextView"; text = "Die Futtermenge kann bei Hunden ab 12 Monaten anhand des Schiebreglers von 2% auf 5% des Körpergewichts verstellt werden. Als Standart empfehlen wir 2% Futter vom Körpergewicht Ihres Hundes. Je nach Aktivität kann das abweichen. Wenn Sie bereits eine hohe Menge an Futter geben und Sie der Meinung sind, es ist nicht ausreichend, erhöhen Sie die Fettmenge im Futter. Mehr unter den Fragen & Antworten.\n \nFür Welpen und Junghunde gilt:\nWelpen 8 - 20 Woche: 7%\nJunghunde 21 - 35 Woche: 6%\nJunghunde 36 - 52 Woche: 5%"; ObjectID = "TAc-yh-nWQ"; */
"TAc-yh-nWQ.text" = "As of 12 months of age, you can use the slide ruler to adjust the food amount for dogs from 2% to 5% of body weight. As a baseline, we recommend 2% of your dog's weight to determine the amount of food. It will vary depending on activity. If you are already giving your dog a lot of food and you feel it is not sufficient, increase the fat content of the food. More information can be found in the FAQ section.\n \nFor puppies and young dogs:\nPuppies 8 - 20 weeks: 7%\nYoung dogs 21 - 35 weeks: 6%\nYoung dogs 36 - 52 weeks: 5%";
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Getreide:"; ObjectID = "VMF-xs-WfF"; */
"VMF-xs-WfF.text" = "Grains:";
/* Class = "IBUIButton"; normalTitle = "Gewicht aktualisieren..."; ObjectID = "WpP-c7-ipY"; */
"WpP-c7-ipY.normalTitle" = "Update weight...";
```

Is there something wrong with my Main.strings? The above is an excerpt.

Comment: Does it work any better if you use the _.xliff_ approach?

Comment: Have not tried that, i don't know how to do that. Can You Tell me how?

Comment: Some lousy bug from Apple? I am having that issue too.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is [a long-standing bug discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426421/uitextview-localized-with-xib-strings-file).

You could try the "Change "Localizable Strings" to "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch XIB"" method recommended there, which seems like a strange bit of voodoo magic but hey if it works it works. Otherwise, setting it at runtime appears necessary.

Comment: the method of setting it to XIB and back to strings do not work for iOS 9.

Comment: Just wanted to say, this "bug" still exists... very strange. After all this time it should have been fixed. I guess the developers have better things to do like drinking a coffee or eating an apple.

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to localise the textviews by code with Localizable.strings files.

Comment: it is amazing how Apple never fixes any bug. Today is February 2020, the bug still persists in iOS and macOS.