# Passing data through ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I'm developing an app that will support multiple languages and I'm looking for the best way to set the different languages.

The app works with a `UINavigationController`. In the first `ViewController` you can select the language pressing a `UIButton` and then in the following view controllers the labels' texts would be changed to the corresponding language.

The way I'm doing it right now is by changing the value of a `BOOL` property when I create the instance of the new `ViewController` depending on the `UIButton` sender tag.

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(void)goToSecondVC{

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        secondVC.english = YES;
    }else{
        secondVC.english = NO;
    }


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:startScreenVC];

}
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if(self.english){
        self.myLabel.text = @"This text will be in English";
    }else{
        self.myLabel.text = @"This text will be in Spanish";
}
```

I know this is probably not the best way to achieve this task. What would you recommend, notifications, delegation, singletons? I'm looking for a kind of global variable that could be written and read from every `ViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is straightforward and correct.

Since you want to have this information known to every view controller, a better approach is to use KVO and a store for the language info value.

For example, save it to NSUserDefaults. Then from any view controller your could access it.

Then if some view controller wants to get notification when this value gets changed, it could observe the NSUserDefaults object for that value. (with Storyboard, you could use a Shared User Defaults Controller).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using localization for this.

You can get the language like this:
`NSString   *language = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];`
Take a look at this this tutorial for localization:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios 
or [this SO ansawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417725/how-to-localize-label-strings-in-ios-for-a-beginner)

Comment: Using localization is the only sane answer. I also recommend the cs193p course available on iTunes U. The most recent version has a lecture about localization.

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the language of the app without considering the localization.

Comment: You should still utilise localization. Take a look at [this](http://mobdevelopment.me/2012/08/23/localize-ios-app-at-runtime/) haven't read it all, but he seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will give your solution a deeper look but for the moment I'm going to implement the `NSUserDefaults` approach since it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the current language setting from any place in your app its worth taking a look at the Singleton design pattern. [Here's an excellent summary](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).

You can also use the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` which is a predefined Singleton object or simply create your own.